# With ggplot, use both unit_format and dollar_format from scales for tick text labeling

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created the following ggplot to highlight my issue:

```
mydf = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(1,2,3,4,5))
ggplot(data = mydf) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar_format()) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::unit_format(unit = "M"))
```

which gives the following amazing, advanced ggplot graph:

[image]

My question is then simply - how can i make one axis have **both the $ and M unit** labels, so that the label shows as $1M $2M, etc. Is this possible? Is it also possible to reduce the gap between the number and the M sign, so that it shows `5M` instead of `5 M`

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hacky, but works:

```
ggplot(data = mydf) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar_format()) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar_format(prefix="$", suffix = "M"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also define your own function:

```
ggplot(data = mydf) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = f <- function(x) paste0("$",x,"M")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = f)
```

Answer (score 1):

A method using y with unit_format() function to generate desired result - tick label y as "$1M", no gap between dollar and amount, no gap between amount and M:

```
mydf = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(1,2,3,4,5))

ggplot(data = mydf) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar_format()) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::unit_format(unit = "M", prefix = "$", sep = "", accuracy = 1))
```

Using Roman's method - since y is using dollar format, results are same without prefix = "$" argument in dollar_format() function:

```
ggplot(data = mydf) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar_format()) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar_format(suffix = "M"))
```